# Transforming a worded problem into a integer programing system of equations

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

> **Past Paper Question:**

**(Record Company Problem)** The Record-a-Song Company has contracted with a rising star to record **eight** songs. The durations of the diﬀerence songs are $8, 3, 5, 5, 9, 6, 7,$ and $12$ minutes, respectively.

Record-a-Song uses a two-sided cassette tape for the recording. Each side has a **capacity** of $30$ minutes.

The company would like to distribute the songs between the **two sides** 
such that the length of the songs on each sides is **about the same**.

> **Aim:**
>
> Formulate this problem as an integer programming problem. Clearly deﬁne 
>   your variables, objective and constraints.

(You are **NOT** required to solve this integer programming problem.)

> > I've put in **bold** the information above that I think would be usfull if this were linear programing problem.
> >
> > The thinks the numbers in the first paragraph would form the coefficients to some inequality, the second paragraph would be the right hand side limiting that inequality:
> >     $$8x_1+3x_2+5x_3+5x_4+9x_5+9x_6+6x_7+7x_8+12x_9\leq 30$$
> >     $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8,x_9)\in\mathbb B$?
> >
> > Not sure where the information of the third paragraph would come in, or what the objective function is.
> >
> > What is the general method to formulate a worded problem and how do you know if your on the right tracks?

Comment: What is your $\mathbb B$ set, the set of basis $0,1$? An integer programming problem will come in two types a binary case and an integer case.

Comment: @HELP yes the notation I've used is the same in my lecture notes and is the binary set, I was thinking that in the wording of the problem, that the variables will only be either $0,1$ since there are durations.

Comment: Ok that might be your first issue, there are 8 songs so i think it will only be 8 variables, and in addition usually when you use the binary set, the summation of all the variables in the inequality are at most 1. So i think in this problem the set your looking for is $\mathbb z_+$, that is the set of positive integers and not the binary set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_{ij}=1$ if and only if song $i\in S$ of duration $d_i$ is assigned to side $j$ of the tape, $j=1,2$.

You want to minimize the difference between the durations on both sides, that is, minimize
$$
Z=|\sum_{i\in S}d_i x_{i1}-\sum_{i\in S}d_i x_{i2}|
$$
subject to:

1. Total durations cannot exceed capacity $30$:
   $$
   \sum_{i\in S}d_i x_{ij}\le  30 \quad \forall j=1,2
   $$
2. Each song must be assigned to either side $1$ or $2$:
   $$
   x_{i1}+x_{i2}=1\quad \forall i\in S
   $$
3. Variables are binaries:
   $$
   x_{ij}\in \{0,1\}\quad \forall i,j
   $$

Of course, you need to linearize the objective function, this is easy: replace the objective function by $Z=\varepsilon$ and add the following constraints:
$$
\sum_{i\in S}d_i x_{i1}-\sum_{i\in S}d_i x_{i2} \le \varepsilon\\
\sum_{i\in S}d_i x_{i2}-\sum_{i\in S}d_i x_{i1} \le \varepsilon
$$

Comment: Ok i have a few questions: where does the information of the question come into this (e.g. the duration being less than 30 minuets), why do we use a summation, why is it not the set of integers like i discussed above, how do you linearize something?

Comment: @HELP he has defined S as a set, so it contains the 8 variables like you discussed, and the duration, d, is w.r.t i. So I think this should contain the data. But I don't know what linearization is, it might be in my lecture notes and I haven't come across it yet.